# SQL JOIN on same table with 2 conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I need to combine 2 columns into 1 row. The key between the columns is the `post_id`.

Here is my table (postmeta):

```
post_id     meta_key    meta_value
36          cp_state    California
37          cp_state    Illinois
38          cp_state    California
39          cp_state    California
40          cp_state    California
36          cp_city     Los Angeles
37          cp_city     Chicago
38          cp_city     San Diego
39          cp_city     San Diego
40          cp_city     Los Angeles
```

And here is what im trying to output:

```
post_id     state       city
36          California  Los Angeles
37          Illinois    Chicago
38          California  San Diego
39          California  San Diego
40          California  Los Angeles
```

Here is the SQL i used but get a crazy amount of results:

```
SELECT a.post_id AS pID, a.meta_value AS state, b.meta_value AS city
FROM $wpdb->prefix"."postmeta AS a
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->prefix"."postmeta AS b
ON b.post_id = a.post_id
WHERE a.meta_key = 'cp_state'
AND b.meta_key = 'cp_city'
```

In the live Wordpress table im using, there's obviously hundreds of other `meta_key`, so i need it to filter just for these 2 `meta_key` (`cp_city`, `cp_state`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT a.post_id AS pID, a.meta_value AS state, b.meta_value AS city
FROM       $wpdb->prefix"."postmeta AS a
INNER JOIN $wpdb->prefix"."postmeta AS b
ON b.post_id = a.post_id
WHERE a.meta_key = 'cp_state'
AND b.meta_key = 'cp_city'
```

Comment: wow! I swear i tried this type of join and couldnt get it to work! Thank you so much :)